# Transaction ID in MySQL Trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

Is there a way to retrieve a transaction ID inside a MySQL trigger?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Currently, [no](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=12866). It's been an open request for four years. However, you can use [`connection_id()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_connection-id) which will give the connection session, so you can group things by that.